# Shortest way to obtain last day of previous month with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

Is there a shorter/more elegant way to reformulate this expression whilst achieving the same result ?

```
Date.today.last_month.end_of_month
```

Comment: Not really... you can also try `Date.today.beginning_of_month - 1.day` but it's not any prettier.

Answer (score 6):

The one you've already written is short and elegant enough still you can try these

```
Date.today - Date.today.day
```

or even shorter version will be to use a variable to limit the words you can try:

```
(a=Date.today) - a.day
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think this is nice but the original statement is better to read and understand.

Answer (score 4):

You want the end of the month. For which month? The last one. Last with respect to what? Today.

So you have said exactly what you are looking for and got it. What is inelegant about that?

If you want shorter:

```
def end_of_last_month
  Date.today.last_month.end_of_month
end
```

Comment: You could pass the base date as an argument with a default value of `Date.today` (or `Date.current`).